# Matlab: How to load a file as array of structs

Tags: matlab

I am trying to convert data file (here string representing file with three lines) into a structure array like this:

```
cel = textscan('1 1.1 2 2.2 3 3.3', '%u %f');
str = cell2struct(cel, {'f1', 'f2'}, 2);
```

However, now I have a struct array of dimension 1x1, where I can only access the columns using array's fields, but not the whole rows (like 'str(2)' for the second row).

What I need is to have an array of structs (or how it can be called) like this:

```
str = struct('f1', {1, 2, 3}, 'f2', {1.1, 2.2, 3.3});
```

because now I can (for instance) filter it like this:

```
subStr = str(find([str.f1] > 1))
```

which I could not do in the first case.
Any idea how to get there?
At the end I was able to do it by:

```
cel = textscan('1 1.1 2 2.2 3 3.3', '%u %f');
[f1, f2] = cel{:};
str = struct('f1', num2cell(f1'), 'f2', num2cell(f2'));
```

But it does not feel right and I am afraid it will be expensive (the files are quite large).

EDIT:

My solution is indeed too memory demanding, therefore not usable.
Typical files have header, footer, and c. 5e6 lines of data in six columns.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) for this? It seems like `struct`s would needlessly complicate your life...

Comment: @Dev-iL I don't mind using `table`. I know `struct` from `numpy` where I find them quite usefull. However as I pointed in comment to your answer, they seem to be memory demanding (and probably overkill for my usecase).

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you're *actually* working with a file that contains lines. For example, if `data.txt` contains:

```
1 1.1
2 2.2
3 3.3
```

And now you can simply load this using:

```
tbl = readtable('data.txt');
tbl.Properties.VariableNames = {'f1', 'f2'};
```

Which results in much nicer (imho) filtering syntax:

```
subTbl = tbl(tbl.f1 > 1, :);
```

I suggest you read a bit about [tables in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html), to learn about their (many) capabilities.

---

Finally, if you insist on working with `struct` arrays, you can do:

```
str = table2struct(tbl); 3×1 struct array with fields: f1 f2
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Tables. However, those files have c. 5e6 lines, plus header and footer. Using `textscan` I can efficiently process the header, footer and data continuously (it reads from current position in file). Using `readtable` however this will probably not be that easy (also not sure how to handle footer). But mainly the script get soon terminated due to lack of memory. So I rather stay with `textscan`...

Comment: Well, you didn't specify the size of the input file. In that case, see article on creating tall arrays, and specifically [tall tables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/tall-arrays.html#bvayjn0).

Comment: Its not like the array would not fit into memory. In matter of fact it occupy only c.100 MB. What consumes the memory is the processing/rearanging (or whatever). I was actually considering `datastores` (or something similar from that area) before, but it turned out that simple `textscan` seemed to be more straightforward considering the structure of the file. Together with following `cell2struct` it is reasonable fast and memory efficient. And I choose structs because they work just fine for me (only if they would be arranged the way I like). But I will give it a second look...

Comment: @rad followup question: are you working with many such files, or is it just the one and you're loading it from text each time? What I mean to say is that maybe it would make sense to preprocess the file once (by even loading it into excel and saving as XLSX, since that would already be simpler for MATLAB to handle - i.e. number saved as numbers and not as text), or of course as a .mat file. It's important to understand which step of the processing you want to focus on making efficient. It might be worth it to perform a costly conversion (once) to gain powerful tools to analyze your data.

Comment: You are probably right about the conversion. The current file structure does not allow for easy parsing into some more 'sophisticated' Matlab data structures. So first I will probably focuse on converting the data file into some more easily managable format and then choose a proper way how to handle it for actual processing. And you were right, it probably won't be a struct arrays...

Answer (score 0):

Each element of `cel` is an array. Using `cellfun` and `num2cell` they can be converted to cell arrays:

```
names = {'f1', 'f2'};
cel = textscan('1 1.1 2 2.2 3 3.3', '%u %f');
cel2 = cellfun(@num2cell, cel, 'UniformOutput', 0);

prep = [names;cel2];
str = struct(prep{:}).';
```

Comment: This does indeed work for small files/cells, but for large ones it consumes to much memory (gets terminated in my case). The `cell2struct` in my case (which however leads to non-optimaly arranged struct array) takes (almost) no time and no memory (since it probably only somehow remap the data in memory). So I was hoping there will be a way how to do it in similar manner...

Comment: You may need to design a class overloading the `subsref` and `subsasgn` operators. the Underlying structure of it can be a cell array `cel` or a struct.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I would read those more carefully sooner, but according to [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html) and [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-allocation.html#brh72ex-14) it is not encouraged to save large datasets the way I was trying to, because

> Structures with many fields and small contents have a large overhead and should be avoided. A large array of structures with numeric scalar fields requires much more memory than a structure with fields containing large numeric arrays.

and

> For structures and cell arrays, MATLAB creates a header not only for each array, but also for each field of the structure and for each cell of a cell array. Because of this, the amount of memory required to store a structure or cell array depends not only on how much data it holds, but also on how it is constructed.

So therefore array `str.f(1:N)` requires (for larger N) much more memory than `str(1:N).f`.

Comment: I'm happy that you reached a useful conclusion, however, I feel that this answer is incomplete. You should update it with the solution you will have ended up using, since at the moment it doesn't really answer the question (the future reader will know what they _shouldn't_ do, but not what they _should_). Your answer will be **very** useful should you document your comparison of different storage mechanisms (which I suspect you'll investigate anyway). Please take this into consideration.